# Loop with Row Count and Merge Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck on a `merge`, i have done a few merges before in my limited experience but this one has baffled me.

I have a dynamic document that has a table inserted, this is based on a table in a static sheet.  I need my code to merge certain columns. These need to apply only to that row.  e.g. on row 57 columns B:E should merge and then the same on row 58.

Here is the snapshot of my code that is doing this section: -

```
With Sheet27
    For rDoc = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Rows + 1 Step 1
        .Cells(rDoc, 5).Copy
        Sheet13.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Sheet13.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).Style = "Normal_TO"
        Sheet13.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).Font.Size = "7"
        Sheet13.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Sheet13.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Sheet13.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Sheet13.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Sheet13.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Sheet13.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Sheet13.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Sheet13.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Cells(rDoc, 6).Copy
        Sheet13.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Sheet13.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).Style = "Normal_TO"
        Sheet13.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).Font.Size = "7"
        Sheet13.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Sheet13.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Sheet13.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Sheet13.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Sheet13.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Sheet13.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Sheet13.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Sheet13.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        Sheet13.Range("B" & Rows.Count & ":E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).Merge '<---This is the part I am stuck on
        .Cells(rDoc, 7).Copy
        Sheet13.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .Cells(rDoc, 8).Copy
        Sheet13.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Next rDoc
End With
```

`Sheet27` looks like the below, this could be anything from 2 rows to 30+ rows.

[image]

`Sheet13` looks like the below,

[image]

The reason for the `rows.count` is because the sheet is based on a userform that the user can choose which sections appear, an each of these sections can dynamically grow based on other data.

Hopefully that makes sense.

In a nut shell i would like a way to get the loop to do a merge with something like this `Sheet13.Range("B" & Rows.Count & ":E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).Merge`

I have tried the above and several other variants.

Desired result as per the below: -

[image]

Some of the things i have tried are: -

```
Sheet13.Range(.Cells(Rows.Count, 2), .Cells(Rows.Count, 3), .Cells(Rows.Count, 4), .Cells(Rows.Count, 5)).Merge

Sheet13.Range(.Cells(Rows.Count, 2), .Cells(Rows.Count, 5)).Merge

Sheet13.Range(.Cells(Rows.Count, 2), .Cells(Rows.Count, 5)).End(xlUp).Rows.Merge
```

Thank you,

Comment: I have found a temp solution but it isnt good enough for a long term solution.  I change sheet 27 to be in the format that i want.  Which is subject to error as it is a user input and then use `union` the columns now maging a merge, paste value and then paste format.  As it is a user input screen i am not a fan, as one of them will change the format and break it.

Comment: Will the number of columns you want to merge always be the same for each group (i.e. document title)?

Comment: @MG92 Yes that is correct for that table.  Just a note that table may not appear in the same place twice as it is based on user selection. i.e. i cant apply anything to the sheet before this table comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up the code a bit, try this:

```vb
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheet13

With Sheet27
    For rDoc = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1 Step 1
        lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value = .Cells(rDoc, 5).Value
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Style = "Normal_TO"
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Font.Size = "7"
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter

        ws.Range("B" & lRow).Value = .Cells(rDoc, 6).Value
        ws.Range("B" & lRow).Style = "Normal_TO"
        ws.Range("B" & lRow).Font.Size = "7"
        ws.Range("B" & lRow).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ws.Range("B" & lRow).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ws.Range("B" & lRow).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ws.Range("B" & lRow).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ws.Range("B" & lRow).Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ws.Range("B" & lRow).Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ws.Range("B" & lRow).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        ws.Range("B" & lRow).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        ws.Range("B" & lRow & ":E" & lRow).Merge

        ws.Range("F" & lRow).Value = .Cells(rDoc, 7).Value
        ws.Range("F" & lRow & ":H" & lRow).Merge

        ws.Range("I" & lRow).Value = .Cells(rDoc, 8)
    Next rDoc
End With
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you so much! I had to make a few tweeks to get it to work with the other code.  Also very nice to learn how you can compact the code further, thank you! :-)

Comment: Just a note the few tweaks were just things to change references where used before such as `lRow` which was used in the code above this section.  Simple change and your code still worked and helped me a great deal.  Thank you :-)